# How do I cast dd/mm/yyyy string into date in BigQuery?

Tags: datetime, casting, google-bigquery, string-to-datetime

I have 3 columns 
1. dd/mm/yyyy (stored as a string)
2. app_id and #downloads of apps

I have to find unique ids of apps downloaded within a week.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert your dd/MM/yyyy strings into BigQuery timestamps using something like the following:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(year + '-' + month + '-' + day) as output_timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(input_date, '.*/([0-9]{4})$') as year, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(input_date, '^([0-9]{2}).*') as day, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(input_date, '.*/([0-9]{2})/.*') AS month 
  FROM 
    (SELECT '30/10/2015' as input_date),
    (SELECT '25/01/2015' as input_date)
)
```

Once you have converted them to timestamps, you may find the [date and time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions) useful, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: By converting to TIMESTAMP first, doesn't this have the risk of losing dates before the year 1970? Isn't that the limit of TIMESTAMP?

Comment: TIMESTAMP actually supports years 1 through 9999, per our docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type.  Though those docs are for standard SQL, legacy SQL timestamps also support the same range.

Answer (score 23):

Even shorter using standard SQL:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','23/03/2015'))
```

Comment: `PARSE_DATE` is not a BigQuery function

Comment: yes it does work thanks a lot, however don't know why PARSE_DATE doesn't appear in the intellisense list created by Bigquery Mate plugin

Comment: PARSE_DATE is definitely a BigQuery function - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date

Answer (score 4):

Shorter with REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
SELECT ds, 
   TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(ds, r'(..)/(..)/(....)', r'\3-\2-\1')) ts
FROM (SELECT '23/03/2015' ds)
```

**EDIT**

Updated version for non-leading zero dates:

```
SELECT ds, 
   TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(ds, r'(.?.)/(..)/(....)', r'\3-\2-\1')) ts
FROM (SELECT '1/01/2017' ds)
```