# BigQuery - Convert date string into timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I am streaming inserts into bigquery from adwords javascript. The javascript time stamp that gets inserted into the bigquery table as a string - "Sun Sep 06 2015 02:42:54 GMT-0700 (PDT)". How do i convert this string into a timestamp of format "2015-09-06 02:42:54" in a bigquery select statement.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by parsing out each part of the date (year, month, day, etc.) using the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function, then constructing a string to pass into the `TIMESTAMP` function.  You can check out the [query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference) for more info on these functions.  See also: [a similar question with a different initial date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016912/how-do-i-cast-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-date-in-bigquery/).

Note however that BigQuery TIMESTAMPs are stored as UTC times, so you may want to shift the time according to the timezone in the string.