# How do I cast spelled out weekday month in string format to date in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to convert my spelled out weekday and month to timestamp format in Bigquery.

My dates are currently stored as `Mon Jul 27 07:08:00 +0000 2015` and I want to convert them to `2015-07-27 07:08:00 UTC`

I have read answer from [How do I cast dd/mm/yyyy string into date in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016912/how-do-i-cast-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-date-in-bigquery) and tried to format it the following way

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(year + '-' + month + '-' + day) as output_timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(created_at, '.*/([0-9]{4})$') as year, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(created_at, '^([0-9]{2}).*') as day, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(created_at, r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)') AS month  
)

[dataset.tablename] where collected_at = "2016-01-01 00:00:01" LIMIT 100
```

However, I get this error `query: SELECT query which references non constant fields or uses aggregation functions or has one or more of WHERE, OMIT IF, GROUP BY, ORDER BY clauses must have FROM clause. (error code: invalidQuery)`

How can I convert it to the format I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql), you have [PARSE_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#parse_timestamp) function with lots of [format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-timestamp), so you can convert your string into `TIMESTAMP`, and if later you need to build custom string out of it, you can use `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP`.
In your example the following format string would work:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%a %b %d %T +0000 %E4Y", t) FROM
(SELECT 'Mon Jul 27 07:08:00 +0000 2015' t)
```

Formats used:

```
%a - Abbreviated weekday
%b - Abbrevialted month
%d - Time in HH:MM:SS
%E4Y - 4 digits year
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For those who might try this you also need to uncheck SQL Version   Use Legacy SQL so that this code work. Else you will get 'bigquery Error: 2.24 - 2.84'.